# rethinkdb eqJoin on multiple fields

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I want to run a query using join on two very large tables.
What is the equivalent rethinkdb syntax for this sql?

```
SELECT t1.uuid,t1.timestamp,t2.name
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.uuid=t2.uuid AND t1.timestamp=t2.timestamp
```

For the example reference, this is the sql for the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    uuid CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    timestamp CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE t2(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    uuid CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    timestamp CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty solution would be:

```
r.table("t1").innerJoin(
  r.table("t2"),
  function (doc1, doc2) {
    return doc1("uuid").eq(doc2("uuid"))
        .and(doc1("timestamp").eq(doc2("timestamp")));
}).zip()
```

But you may want to create a compound index on those fields

```
r.table("t1").indexCreate(
    "myIndex", [r.row("uuid"), r.row("timestamp")])


r.table("t2").indexCreate(
    "myIndex", [r.row("uuid"), r.row("timestamp")])


r.table("t1").eqJoin(
    "myIndex",
    r.table("t2"),
    {index: "myIndex"}
).zip()
```